# How to find element value based on attribute value from xml using xpath?

Tags: xpath

This is the file (1.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<traceCollecFile xmlns="http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/specs/archive/32_series/32.423#traceData" >
<fileHeader fileFormatVersion="32.423 V10.0" vendorName="CDOT GROUP" >
<fileSender elementDn="DC=a1.companycdot.com,SubNetwork=1, ManagedElement=MME-1_1_1" elementType="MME" />
</fileHeader>
<traceRecSession dnPrefix="DC=a1.companycdot.com,SubNetwork=1" traceRecSessionRef="992" stime="2018-06-08T13:47:12-05:30" >
<ue idType="IMSI" idValue="311480000002255" />
<msg function="S6" name="UPDATE LOCATION ANSWER" changeTime="0.000000" vendorSpecific="false" >
<ie name="RESULT_CODE">2001</ie>
</msg>
<traceSessionRef >
<MCC>311</MCC>
<MNC>480</MNC>
<TRACE_ID>8323073</TRACE_ID>
</traceSessionRef>
</traceRecSession>
<traceRecSession dnPrefix="DC=a1.companycdot.com,SubNetwork=1" traceRecSessionRef="992" stime="2018-06-08T13:47:12-05:30" >
<ue idType="IMSI" idValue="311480000002255" />
<msg function="S11" name="CREATE SESSION REQUEST" changeTime="0.000000" vendorSpecific="false" >
<ie name="GTP_V2_IE_IMSI">311480000002255</ie>
<ie name="GTP_V2_IE_RAT_TYPE">6</ie>
<ie name="GTP_V2_IE_MSISDN">913114802255</ie>
<ieGroup name="GTP_V2_IE_FQ_CSID" >
<ie name="INSTANCE">0</ie>
<ie name="GTP_V2_IE_FQ_CSID">1</ie>
</ieGroup>
<ieGroup name="GTP_V2_IE_BEARER_CNTXT" >
<ie name="INSTANCE">0</ie>
<ie name="GTP_V2_IE_EBI">5</ie>
<ieGroup name="GTP_V2_IE_BEARER_QOS" >
<ie name="ARP">92</ie>
<ie name="QCI">9</ie>
<ie name="UPLINK_MBR">0</ie>
<ie name="DOWNLINK_MBR">0</ie>
<ie name="UPLINK_GBR">0</ie>
<ie name="DOWNLINK_GBR">0</ie>
</ieGroup>
</ieGroup>
<ie name="GTP_V2_IE_APN">vzwinternet.mnc480.mcc311.gprs</ie>
</msg>
<traceSessionRef >
<MCC>311</MCC>
<MNC>480</MNC>
<TRACE_ID>8323073</TRACE_ID>
</traceSessionRef>
</traceRecSession>
</traceCollecFile>
```

I want only the element whose attribute value is GTP_V2_IE_MSISDN .
    I have tried code in php using xpath.

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('1.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
// If you want to read exact attribute
//Selects all the ie elements that have a "name" attribute with a value of "GTP_V2_IE_MSISDN".
 $MSISDN = $xpath->query("//traceCollecFile/traceRecSession/msg/ie[@name='GTP_V2_IE_MSISDN']");
 if ($MSISDN->length > 0) {
    echo $MSISDN->item(0)->value;
 }
```

But nothing is displayed in output when i run in browser.On console it displays nothing in HTML code, body is empty.
Please help ,what is wrong ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have a default namespace.

```
xmlns="http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/specs/archive/32_series/32.423#traceData"
```

Define it in php or try the below expression

```
//@*[. = "GTP_V2_IE_MSISDN"]/..
```